# QVector of objects to display on List (Widget or Model)?

Tags: c++, qt

So ive got a Qvector which contains objects of a 'contact' class....the contact class so far looks like this:

```
class contact {
        QString firstName;
        QString lastName;
        QString email;
        QString age;
        QString imgSrc;

public:
   contact();
   contact(QString fName, QString lname, QString emailAdd, QString new_Age, QString img);
   QString getPerson(); // return  "James Smith 34" which i add to listwidget   
};
```

Thats very trivial, the problem ive come across is whats the most effective way for me to display this data in a list format, i.e

Adam Smith 34

John Smith 43

Should i use a basic list widget ?? ( considering i have to sort the information  into accesnding and descending orders...

or do i use list view ?? but which model ??

Comment: First you need to tell us _how_ you want the information displayed, as it is that which determines what widget to use.  You can't ask us to decide that for you.

Comment: currently the information is stored at runtime in a QVector of objects (contacts)The information should be displayed in the order of FirstName Lastname age, making one row.From that list of contacts I should be able to delete, sort by age descending/ascending.Whats the best way to go from a Qvector of objects to a listView/listWidget, which ever is suitable.
Is it a bit clearer now ?

Answer (score 1):

You will have subclass `QAbstractTableModel` in order to provide a model interface to reading the contact information, read the docs [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QAbstractTableModel.html#details).  You won't need to bother with delegates as you are just displaying text.

The default `QTableView` should be sufficient, remember to implement the [header data methods](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#headerData) in `QAbstractTableModel` otherwise you won't see the column header labels in the view.

To provide sorting functionality you will need to provide a custom `QSortFilterProxyModel` between the model and view.  The [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#details) provide great examples of how to use it.

Qt's [MVC framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html) can be very daunting at first, but once you understand it's modular structure, it becomes clear what you need to do to get certain functionality.  It's *incredibly* powerful, but has a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: Thanks I had a look, but using the QAbstractTableModel is over-complicating it because I did manage to populate the listWidget quite easily simply by looping through all the contacts stored in my vector and calling the addItem function from listWidget on each one. So really the vector of objects is serving the purpose of a model. The problem is how would I manipulate the information ?? do I modify the vector then re-populate the listWidget ?? this is why I'm curious about a model that wont require constant re-populating of my actual front-end list

Comment: And this is why Qt has an MVC framework, as soon as you try to do anything beyond statically displaying the data, it falls apart pretty quickly.  Remember your vector of objects will always be the 'displayed' data, the model simply provides a wrapper so that the other MVC components can access this data through a consistent interface.  In other words once you have the model/view setup, changing the vector of objects will automatically update _any_ view connected to the model.

Comment: Ok then considering Im fairly new to the Qt MVC, is there such an existing model which is will communicate in the depiction of    Qvector <-> model <-> QtListView ?? So manipulating the Vector will alter the connected model and views

Comment: No, because you are (quite rightfully) storing your data in a custom class - how would a stock Qt model class know how to access the data in it?  Also you said you wanted the ability to sort by column, so you need a table-based model, not a list-based one.

Comment: Thats right I understand,and no I made a mistake its not really a sort, but having to find the oldest contact and re-populate the view so it only displays him/her and similarly with youngest, as well as basic CRUD operation.

Thanks for the advice so far though really appreciate it